# add a conditional start date to a payment function

Tags: date, if-statement, excel-formula, finance

I am building a financial model and adding loan payments, and want the payments to start on a conditional start date.

I can calculate the PMT amount for a loan, but cant seem to get the payments PMT to show up in the specific start date (month) and to end when the balance is 0.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VWzk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWyKG.png)

I have a start date in Column J and calculated the payment, but I get an error message.

I tried the following, but not sure where I am going wrong.

J61 pmt start date either Jan 1 or June 1 2023
S2- start of the month
S4- end of the month
PMT(rate, nper, pv, [fv], [type]) this works
NPER= number of payments

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(J61>S3,J61<=S4,1,0)),PMT(G61/H61,I61*H61,F61))
```

Not sure how to incorporate the ending balance into this formula.
End date with Balance equals= 0

Comment: Could you please give more information, possibly an example screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? You are using a lot of cell references (e.g. J61, S3 etc.) and it is not clear what kind of information they contain.

Comment: The problem you are stating can probably be resolved very quickly once you refined your question's clarity.

Comment: added an image, the cell references have changed a bit.  I want the PMTs to start in the month J column and go until the balance is =0. I manually put in the payments given the start date but would like to automate it.

Comment: When you type *I get an error message*, the very next thing that should go in your post is the **complete, exact error message** that you're getting. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us for help solving YOUR problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to provide that help by giving us the details that you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Since your financial model has monthly granularity of calculations, it is not clear how you want to allocate the payments for loans that have intra-month start dates.

Here is a very simple solution that will not allocated pro rata for the days of a month, but allocated the total monthly payments starting with the month of the start date.

```
=(S$4>=$J61)*(S$4<=EDATE($J61,$H61)-1)*$K61
```

Which looks like this

[image: screenshot_1]

So, as you can see in the screenshot, although the start date for the 1st loan is the 31st of January, there will already occur the full PMT amount for the month of January in the timeline.